# Is Riemann integration only concerned with rates of change?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Consider the Riemann integrable function $f(x)$. Whenever I see the expression
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \ dx
$$
I read this as
$$
\int_a^b \frac{dF(x)}{dx} \ dx
$$
where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. In other words, I consider every Riemann integral to be concerned with integrating a "rate of change", which in this case is $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$. Is this thinking correct? That is, do all Riemann integrals take in a "rate of change" as an input?

Comment: Don't confuse definition and calculation... The Riemann integral has a precise definition that does not mention or require the existence of antiderivative.

Comment: I am aware that a Riemann integral is the limit of a Riemann sum, but how is this relevant to whether every function that is Riemann integrable is the derivative of some other function?

Comment: Not all Riemann integrable functions have an antiderivative. When they have, it can be used to compute the integral.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not true in general. For instance, take the step function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\leq0\\1&x>0\end{cases}$$

It is Riemann integrable on all intervals, but there is no function $F$ whose derivative is $f$. You can prove this using Darboux's theorem (all derivative functions have the intermediate value property, which $f$ does not have), or using the fundamental theorem of calculus: if an antiderivative of a Riemann integrable function on an interval exists, then it is equal to an integral function up to a constant summand. But you can show that the integral functions of $f$ are not differentiable.

Comment: You could also justifying this by noting that $F$ is a differentiable function, then $F'$ never has jump discontinuities or removable discontinuities. This can be proven using the mean value theorem.

Comment: (+1) If $f(x)$ doesn't have an indefinite integral (antiderivative), does it have a definite integral?

Comment: @mhdadk: Not necessarily. Consider the function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $x$ is rational,} \\
0&\text{if $x$ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$
The Riemann integral $\int_{a}^{b}f$ does not exist for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Joe That's essentially Darboux's theorem (the jump discontinuities)

Answer (score 7):

No. Say $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&(x=0),
\\0,&(x\ne0).\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$, but there does not exist a function $F$ with $f=F'$.